# Unable to transfer files to the XBox One in Dev Mode using either the XBox Portal or DurangoFTP for RetroArch

Tags: javascript, ftp, xbox-one, libretro

I bought the Dev Mode license for the Xbox One last week in the hopes of running RetroArch initially for the Amiga emulator.  However I'm running into serious problems before I can even really start.  I've tried the RetroArch forums and Discord but with no luck, so I'm posting here in the hopes someone can help.

I have got as far as activating Dev Mode on the Xbox, downloading and deploying RetroArch through the Xbox Portal, and running RetroArch on the Xbox and updating everything that is needed with no problem.

However what I now need to do is to deploy my kickstart ROMs and image files.

I've now tried three methods:

The first is to connect to the Xbox using the Xbox portal and browse from there to the LocalAppData\RetroArch\LocalState\system folder.  However on trying to expand RetroArch all I get is a long delay and eventually a message box popping up saying

`Failed to get files for package 1e4cf179-f3c2-404f-b9f3-cb2070a5aad8_1.10.3.0_x64_8ngdn9a6dx1ma JavaScript from 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'`

(I apologise if the UID is mistyped, I'm trying to read my handwritten scrawled notes from last week, but you should get the gist).

I then attempted **My Files Explorer**.  I downloaded and deployed this with no issue, but when I ran it on the Xbox it didn't allow me to see anything.  I even tried loading the files I wanted onto my external drive but I couldn't see any removable drives. In fact I even went into the Xbox Storage settings and tried to view the contents of the external drive and it just displayed the Xbox Store background and nothing else, yet I can view the contents when not in Dev Mode (which I find really strange).

My third attempt was a guide from Discord which was to use DurangoFTP.  again I downloaded and deployed this with no problems, ran it on the Xbox, started the server, and could connect to it from my PC with an FTP client (Filezilla in this case).  This displayed a list of drives and a folder called LOCALSTATE.  I was instructed to expand LOCALSTATE before attempting to FTP files, but as soon as I do I get the error

`451 Exception thrown, message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I'm getting to my wits end now and close to giving up completely.  I know I'm not the only person having problems with this, but no one can seem to give me a solution.